# Trying to run my app in my smartphone

Tags: java, android, usb, motorola

I was trying to run my app through my smartphone (a Motorola - Moto G2). For this, I have done the necessary ( installed the USB driver from Motorola and USB debugging), but still does not work. This error appears:

Uploading file
    local path:C:\Users\Felipe\AndroidStudioProjects\ColetordeDados\app\build\outputs\apk\app-debug.apk
    remote path: /data/local/tmp/com.k19.treinamento.coletordedados
Installing com.k19.treinamento.coletordedados
DEVICE SHELL COMMAND: pm install -r "/data/local/tmp/com.k19.treinamento.coletordedados"
pkg: /data/local/tmp/com.k19.treinamento.coletordedados
**Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your SDK to the newest Version. Use the Android SDK Manager.
http://developer.android.com/tools/help/sdk-manager.html

Check in your manifiest that your "android:minSdkVersion" and "android:targetSdkVersion" are correctly set.

Try to set "android:targetSdkVersion" to 23.

And "android:minSdkVersion" to 21

Comment: do you know how I find the right values ​​of android:minSdkVersion" and "android:targetSdkVersion" from my app ? and only need the data or have something else ? I am still beginner

Comment: I update the answer. The targetSdkVersion should be the version of your sdk. And the minSdkVersion depends on your device and the used API in your app. A good guess would be 21, if your G2 is running Android 5.0 or above...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using gradle, edit your build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "your package name"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
}
```